# How to locate elements in mobile app ? (findElement By class, id)

Tags: android, testing, automation, ui-automation, appium

i am learning automation testing with mobile applications.
    When i had gone through some tutorials i found that we can locate elements using UIAutomator Viewer-- by taking screenshot and finding elements.
    But by taking screenshot i could not find elements of some elements.
    So, do we have any other ways to find elements or any other tools like UIAutomator?
    Please help. 
    If u have any good links for mobile automation testing please do forward.
    Thanks.

Comment: Is your application native application or hybrid application? What version of Andriod were you testing?

Comment: Hi  i am using native application with android 5.0

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomator is provided by Android SDK and this is part of Android tools.
You can use the tool that provided by Appium. Please see details and example [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#finding-and-interacting-with-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Install UI automator incase you are using appium in windows, if your using mac, you can identify using appium inspector.

```
find_element(class: "classname")
find_element(id: "resource-id name")
```

if you want to click on them add `.click`

```
find_element(class: "classname").click
```

If your still not having the details of `id` , `text` , `content-desc`, you can choose to add `xpath`

Go through this [link](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html) for more info.

If you are part of testing team, testing on the app being developed, You may raise a bug to the developer in case, there are no unique identifiers and ask the dev team to add one.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to find elements using UIautomatorviewer, you need to highlight the element which you want to find the locator.

If it's not giving you either id, name or xpath then you have to write 
        xpath manually. For writing xpaths manually refer these [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsyl8.png) and [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEowO.png).

As another option, you can use appium desktop client to find the elements in the mobile app. For that you need to follow the below steps,

```
        1. In appium window, click on 'Start Inspector Session' icon
        2. In there you need to add the relevant capabilities there.
```

refer the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEowO.png).

```
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\VWEERAY\\Desktop\\APPIUM\\mediashare.apk");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "192.168.56.101:5555");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidDevice1:5554");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");

        3.Then click on 'Start Session' in the bottom.

        4. It will open with a Mobile view and from there you can find locators like in the uiautomatorviewer.
```